# Spring security, jdbcAuthentication

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am just starting with spring security, and I got a problem when trying to use database for users.

This is where I implemented `WebApplicationInitializer`:

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = 
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/services/rest/*");

    }

}
```

`AppConfiguration` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "glavni")
public class AppConfiguration {

}
```

I have `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
   extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

and `SecurityConfiguration` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DBConnection conn;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(conn.initializeDataSource())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_id, authority from authorization where user_id=?");

    }
}
```

This worked fine with `inMemoryAuthentication()`, the line in `configureGlobal` method that I commented. But when I try to use database I get errors.

I made autowired field conn, from which I can get `dataSource` object configured with Hikari connection pool.

I get this error:

```
 `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'conn'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'glavni.db.DBConnection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4903)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'glavni.db.DBConnection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 more

Jul 17, 2017 12:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/trcanje] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'glavni.db.DBConnection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4903)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoERROR [localhost-startStop-1] (FrameworkServlet.java:502) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'conn'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'glavni.db.DBConnection' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)`
```

Comment: Which kind of errors ?

Comment: Have you added @Bean annotation to 'glavni.db.DBConnection'?

Comment: Try to autowire DataSource directly. like @Autowired
 DataSource dataSource; if you are using Spring boot, otherwise create it bean as well

Comment: @chomnoue I have added `@Component` to DBConnection so it can be autowired, you can only add `@Bean` to methods.

Comment: @Afridi And where can I initialize DataSource?

Comment: If you are using spring boot then it will initialize the db for you

Comment: @wdc If you are using spring boot(application.properties) then no need to initialize its been, otherwise initialize it in any of configuration file. Check this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Comment: @chomnoue I don't. Just SpringWebMvc But I have used Autowired instance of DBConnection in other places in my app, and it worked fine.

Comment: Make sure that the DBConnection bean is created before your Spring Security configuration is loaded. Also please post your `web.xml` if you have one.

Comment: @Ashish How can I make sure that the `DBConnection` bean is created before Spring security configuration is loaded? Also I used Autowired on DBConnection successfully on other classes, but when I add that on this one, spring cannot make bean out of it (out of `SecurityConfiguration` not the DBConnection itself).

Comment: And I don't have `web.xml`.

Comment: If you are using a pure Java based configuration, you should have a class that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` instead of web.xml. Need more information on your configuration here. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: @Ashish Updated.

Comment: Still not enough information. Need `AppConfiguration` actual configuration.

Comment: @Ashish Done. That's all configuration I have.

Comment: It's getting really hard to just tell by what you have here. I recommend that you put your code in GitHub and provide me with a link so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: @Ashish Ok, uploaded to GitHub. https://github.com/gprincip/springsecurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I was missing was spring-jdbc dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Configure datasource in your AppConfiguration class like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManager
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "glavni")
public class AppConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your-database-name");
      dataSource.setUsername( "database-username" );
      dataSource.setPassword( "database-username" );
      return dataSource;
   }

}
```

Note: DriverClassName and Url values are for MySQL. You may change this depending on the database you are using.

Finally, autowire the datasource in your SecurityConfiguration class like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_id, authority from authorization where user_id=?");

    }
}
```

Comment: He already mentioned that the DBConnection was working fine with his other controllers. It seems like he has a problem with the way the beans are loading.

Comment: Yea. I only wanted he to try another approach to see if it works for him. It will be good he upload his project on github as you suggested.